# How to highlight sidebar items even when you are inside a submenu of a particular sidebar item in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In a dashboard layout, let's say I have a sidebar that contains the option 'Leave'. When I click on leave, leave gets highlighted on the sidebar, and the leave component is displayed. In the leave component, there is a button 'Apply Leave'. When I click on 'Apply Leave', the Apply Leave Component containing the form is displayed, but 'Leave' on sidebar is not highlighted anymore.

Also I want to make the sidebar scroll independently of the browser scrolling and show the scrollbars only while scrolling. Just like youtube sidebar which scrolls seperately from the video feed scrollbar.

Here is my code:

Sidebar.js

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import "../assets/styles/Sidebar.css";
import SidebarItem from "./SidebarItem";

function Sidebar() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const pathname = location.pathname;
    const item = getItemFromPathname(pathname);
    setSelectedItem(item);
  }, [location]);

  const getItemFromPathname = (pathname) => {
    const parts = pathname.split("/");
    const lastPart = parts[parts.length - 1];
    switch (lastPart) {
      case "":
      case "profile":
        return "Profile";
      case "calendar":
        return "Calendar";
      case "leave":
        return "Leave";
      default:
        return "";
    }
  };

  const handleItemClick = (title) => {
    setSelectedItem(title);
  };

  return (
    <section className="sidebar">
      <SidebarItem
        to="/"
        title="Profile"
        selected={selectedItem === "Profile"}
        onClick={() => handleItemClick("Profile")}
      />
      <SidebarItem
        to="/calendar"
        title="Calendar"
        selected={selectedItem === "Calendar"}
        onClick={() => handleItemClick("Calendar")}
      />
      <SidebarItem
        to="/leave"
        title="Leave"
        selected={selectedItem === "Leave"}
        onClick={() => handleItemClick("Leave")}
      />
    </section>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

SidebarItem.js

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "../assets/styles/SidebarItem.css"

function SidebarItem(props) {
  return (
    <Link to={props.to} className="sidebar-item-link">
      <div
        className={`sidebar-item ${props.selected && "selected"}`} 
        onClick={props.onClick}
      >
        {props.title}
      </div>
    </Link>
  );
}

export default SidebarItem;
```

SidebarItem.css

```css
.sidebar-item.selected {
  border-left: 10px solid #63809f;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function to check if you are in the route (or subroute) of selected sidebar button.

maybe something like this:

```
function isInRoute(
  // all routes you want to check
  routes: string[],
  // router manager where you can get the current route/subroute
  router: DEFINE_TYPE_HERE,
  // must match the route - usefull with root route (/) 
  // or if must match a subroute (some/thing)
  exactly?: boolean
): boolean {
  if ( !routes || routes.length <= 0 ) return false
  if ( !router ) return false

  const { pathname } = router
  return routes.some( ( route ) => {
    if ( !route || route.trim().length <= 0 ) return false

    /* eslint-disable no-useless-escape */
    const regex = new RegExp(
      // if you don't pass the exactly prop but want to check
      // if you are in root (/) route, you can use it as '\/'
      route === '\/' || exactly ?
        `^${ route }$` : `${ route }`
    )
    return regex.test( pathname )
  } )
}
```

then use it like this:

```
// current route: '/user/xx'

// returns false because you are in a subrouter of /user
isInRoute(
  ['user'],
  YOUR_ROUTER,
  true
) 

// returns true because the root route is /user
isInRoute(
  ['user'],
  YOUR_ROUTER
)
```

hope this helps

PS: if you are using JS instead of TS just remove types in function params

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to switch over to using the [`NavLink`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link) component which includes route path matching functionality already, no need to re-invent the wheel.

Example:

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import "../assets/styles/SidebarItem.css"

function SidebarItem({ title, ...props }) {
  return (
    <NavLink className="sidebar-item-link" {...props}>
      {({ isActive }) => (
        <div className={`sidebar-item ${isActive && "selected"}`}>{title}</div>
      )}
    </NavLink>
  );
}

export default SidebarItem;
```

When the current URL path is `"/leave/*"` (*or `"/calendar/*"`, etc*) the sidebar item will be active, or "selected".

There's likely also no need for the `selectedItem` state in the parent component now since selected/active state is computed by `react-router-dom` and the `NavLink` component.

```
function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <section className="sidebar">
      <SidebarItem to="/" title="Profile" end /> // *
      <SidebarItem to="/calendar" title="Calendar" />
      <SidebarItem to="/leave" title="Leave" />
    </section>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

[image: Edit how-to-highlight-sidebar-items-even-when-you-are-inside-a-submenu-of-a-particula]

**** Note:** The `end` prop is used specifically for `"/"` so it's not also matched with other sub-routes. The alternative here would be to give the Profile page its own non-"/" path, e.g. `"/profile"`.*